# How do I write the SQL query to fetch the data (image) from JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json, json-extract

Json Object

```json
{"images": ["https://bijnis.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2487dc60-c3b5-4cf9-a3a2-34f73683ac5a.jpg"], 
"remarks": "done", 
"documentList": [{"id": "GST", "value": "GST"}]}, GST, https://bijnis.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2487dc60-c3b5-4cf9-a3a2-34f73683ac5a.jpg
```

```sql
select
    json_extract(my_json_field, '$.images'),
    json_extract(my_json_field, '$.remarks'),
    json_extract(my_json_field, '$.documentList.id'),
    json_extract(my_json_field, '$.documentList.value')
from Jason Object;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON_VALUE` as follows :

```
WITH cte as (
select '{"images": ["https://bijnis.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2487dc60-c3b5-4cf9-a3a2-34f73683ac5a.jpg"], 
"remarks": "done", 
"documentList": [{"id": "GST", "value": "GST"}]}' as json
)
select JSON_VALUE(json, '$.images') AS images,
    JSON_VALUE(json, '$.remarks') AS remarks,
    JSON_VALUE(json, '$.documentList[0].id') AS id,
    JSON_VALUE(json, '$.documentList[0].value') AS value
from cte;
```

Comment: from cte c; whats c in here?

Comment: Its an alias not needed, I removed it.